# Is this statement correct : $\frac{dv}{dt}\times dx=\frac{dx}{dt}\times dv$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives, differential

So I just came across a physics derivation where the treat the $dv$ and $dx$ operators like fractions while I have always heard it's a mistake. But so far what I came up with:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dv}{dt}\times dx &= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{v(t+h)-v(t)}h \times (x(t+h)-x(t)) \\
&= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{x(t+h)-x(t)}h \times (v(t+h)-v(t)) \\
&= \frac{dx}{dt}\times dv
\end{align*}$$

Is my reasoning correct? If not please explain what is the correct way to think about this.

Comment: Feel free to take a moment to visit the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to familiarize yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check it out.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being closed. It is fine in my opinion. +1

Comment: @KamalSaleh It wasn't fine initially. OP has been a member for more than one year.

Comment: @KurtG. I understand. But notice that the OP has asked only two questions.

Comment: @KamalSaleh and presumably read many more, including the comments asking for MathJax formatting.

Comment: Back to work: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1180686/949989) contains a fairly rigorous version of what you were doing, @JustPassingby. Nothing really wrong with your approach from my point of view. It is the chain rule in disguise.

Comment: Your limit statement unfortunately doesn't make sense since $dx$ is not the limit of $x(t+h)-x(t)$ which is $0$. The way to make sense of this statement is by the chain rule. [See my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613596/can-i-get-from-fracd2-xdt2-g-to-iint-d2-x-iint-g-dt2/4613609#4613609)

Comment: The limits are certainly equal, because both limits are zero. But when $dv$ is used without a denominator, it doesn't really mean the limit definition of a derivative.

Comment: Thanks for the help all of you!

Answer (score 3):

Just before a differential disappears in the limit we are allowed to view them as small segments of length or small packets of velocity. Even after disappearance their ratio  continues to make sense.

$$ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \to\frac{dy}{dx} =y' = \tan \phi$$
$$ \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s} \to\frac{dx}{ds} =\cos \phi$$
$$ \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta s} \to\frac{dy}{ds} =\sin \phi. $$

[image]

Similarly packets of mass or velocity in a packet (interval) of time made.. even now makes sense in the *Newtonian formulation* of force :

$$ F =\frac{\Delta(m v)}{\Delta t }= \frac{v\Delta m}{\Delta t }+\frac{m\Delta v}{\Delta t }$$

$$\to v\frac{dm}{dt }+m \frac{ dv}{dt } $$

Even after the disappearance of finite differential form their product continues to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, taking the limit doesn't work because technically the limit goes to $0$ as $h\rightarrow0$.  As stated in Narasimham's answer, you think of differentials as representing very small (infinitesimally small), but non-zero, changes.

The rigorous way to derive the statement you mentioned above is:

$$\cfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}\text{d}v=\cfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}\left(\cfrac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}\text{d}x\right)=\cfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}\left(\cfrac{\cfrac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}}{\cfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}}\text{d}x\right)=\cfrac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}\text{d}x\ ,$$ where I used the fact that $\cfrac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=\cfrac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}\cfrac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}$, which is the chain rule.

I think it's good practice to do things more rigorously like this if you ever take (or have taken) multi-variable calculus. Because then differential cancellations are less straightforward.

Comment: This just hit the point point. Thanks for taking your time to help. I kinda got a feeling had to use the chain rule here.